# BigQuery queries validation

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently developing some BigQuery queries for data from Google Analytics (GA), and need a method to asses the validity of the results obtained by them, i.e. that the results returned are correct.

What I am doing so far for validation is to use a combination of the following:

- Running the equivalent queries in GA Query Explorer and comparing the results;
- For the queries for which I cannot directly check in GA Query Explorer, I have a Python script which calculates the expected results.

What are the good practices for this kind of validation? Do you have any further suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: Hi Silvia!  While very interesting, this question isn't really considered on topic for stack overflow, as it will draw in opinionated answers, and Stack doesn't appreciate that. I would suggest trying the google group for App Engine in general (groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine) and asking there, you might get more discussions :)

Comment: Thanks Patrice for your contribution. You are right, I will post there instead!